# PowerShell - Split zip (or any) file into multiple files - Script not working

Tags: powershell, file, split

```
function split($inFile,  $outPrefix, [Int32] $bufSize){

  $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($inFile)
  $chunkNum = 1
  $barr = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

  while( $bytesRead = $stream.Read($barr,0,$bufsize)){
    $outFile = "C:\OutDir\$outPrefix$chunkNum"
    $ostream = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($outFile)
    $ostream.Write($barr,0,$bytesRead);
    $ostream.close();
    echo "wrote $outFile"
    $chunkNum += 1
  }
}

split "C:\File_To_Split.iso" "Splits_" "10240000"
```

I have the above script that I am trying to get working.  I need to split a 1.5GB zip file into 100+ mini files then bring them back together once they have been moved.

When I run the script above, it fails to do anything.  Obviously I'm hosing things up.  Can anyone see where I'm heading south?

Regards,
-Ron

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are calling this function?  I notice its not in your example at the bottom of the script.  I also notice your $outFile doesn't include a full path.  If you are running this in a console session as an admin, its likely putting it in C:\windows\system32.

Comment: Are you actually passing in a buffer size when you use it?  you're also not handling the condition where the buffer+the-last-chunk is larger than the original file -- while this will still work, it will end up making the recombined file a different file than the original.  This may not matter to you but if you're trying to use hash verification after-the-fact, it won't work unless it just-so-happens that the file size is divisible (with no remainder) by the buffer (which is highly unlikely).  You're welcome to use my function I wrote recently for this -- see below.

Comment: Thank you - I corrected the issues and it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *call* the `split` function after defining it.

Add the following:

```
split -inFile $inFile -outPrefix "prefixGoesHere" -bufSize 4MB
```

on a new line at the bottom of the script. Change `"prefixGoesHere"` and `4MB` to the appropriate values you want to pass.

---

If you want to be able to pass arguments to the script itself, add a `param` block at the top of the script, and then pass the arguments to the `split` function:

```
param(
  [string]$inFile = "C:\InnoWake\Server\MiningServer.zip",
  [string]$outPrefix = "",
  [int]$bufSize = 4MB
)

function split($inFile,  $outPrefix, [Int32] $bufSize){

  $stream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($inFile)
  $chunkNum = 1
  $barr = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

  while( $bytesRead = $stream.Read($barr,0,$bufsize)){
    $outFile = "$outPrefix$chunkNum"
    $ostream = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($outFile)
    $ostream.Write($barr,0,$bytesRead);
    $ostream.close();
    echo "wrote $outFile"
    $chunkNum += 1
  }
}

# splatting the $PSBoundParameters variable will pass all the parameter arguments that were originally passed to the script, to the `split` function
split @PSBoundParameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below after this line `$outFile = "$outPrefix$chunkNum"`

```
$outFile = "$((Get-Item -Path $inFile).Directory)\$outFile"
```

then call your function like normal

```
split $inFile $outPrefix $bufSize
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my function I wrote relatively recently -- Chunk-File and Recombine-File.  If nothing else, you can use it as a reference to see how I did it and adapt your script to similar logic:

https://thepip3r.blogspot.com/2021/07/hackem-up-disassembling-and-recombining.html